# Conditional Formatting to range

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

[image: Hours Analysis]

I am trying to do conditional formatting on certain job levels if they reached their target range. How would I go about doing this. For example, if a PM on the left's ratio is higher than 60%, then I want them to turn green, if not, turn red.

Comment: If I had to do what you ask, I would use a conditional formatting with "Use a formula"; to build an actual example, it would have been great to know what row/column you are working in.

Comment: The header "Type Code" in the first table is cell B3 if that helps

Answer (score 1):

[image]

USe a CF rule based on formula:

```
=AND(B1>0.6,A1="PM")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `VLOOKUP` to find target. Formulas for formatting:
For green:

```
=VLOOKUP(B4,$I$4:$K$6,3,FALSE)<=F4
```

For red:

```
=VLOOKUP(B4,$I$4:$K$6,3,FALSE)>F4
```

(change ranges according to yours).

Result:
[image]